# do-release-upgrade from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS - A fatal error occured

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I wanted to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04 LTS using command line.
First of all I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt install -f && sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, these commands were executed without errors. Executing the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` resulted in an unexpected error:

> A fatal error occurred
>
> Please report this as a bug and include the files
> /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in
> your report. The upgrade has aborted.
> Your original sources.list was saved in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade.

cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log:

```
2022-06-01 17:06:33,700 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.bionic', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2022-06-01 17:06:33,700 INFO uname information: 'Linux <HOST> 4.15.0-182-generic #191-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 21 21:31:44 UTC 2022 x86_64'
2022-06-01 17:06:34,297 INFO apt version: '1.6.15'
2022-06-01 17:06:34,297 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Mar 15 2022, 13:55:28) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2022-06-01 17:06:34,303 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.38' started
2022-06-01 17:06:34,318 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2022-06-01 17:06:34,455 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2022-06-01 17:06:34,508 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2022-06-01 17:06:34,845 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2022-06-01 17:06:39,120 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2022-06-01 17:06:39,121 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2022-06-01 17:06:39,121 DEBUG openCache()
2022-06-01 17:06:39,121 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2022-06-01 17:06:39,122 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2022-06-01 17:06:40,597 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-176 with 
2022-06-01 17:06:40,597 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-177 with 4.15.0-176
2022-06-01 17:06:40,598 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-179 with 4.15.0-177
2022-06-01 17:06:40,598 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-181 with 4.15.0-179
2022-06-01 17:06:40,598 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-182 with 4.15.0-181
2022-06-01 17:06:40,599 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-50 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:40,599 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-52 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:40,601 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-58 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:40,978 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 112426
2022-06-01 17:06:40,979 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2022-06-01 17:06:40,979 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2022-06-01 17:06:40,984 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2022-06-01 17:06:45,696 DEBUG openCache()
2022-06-01 17:06:51,437 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-176 with 
2022-06-01 17:06:51,438 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-177 with 4.15.0-176
2022-06-01 17:06:51,438 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-179 with 4.15.0-177
2022-06-01 17:06:51,438 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-181 with 4.15.0-179
2022-06-01 17:06:51,438 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-182 with 4.15.0-181
2022-06-01 17:06:51,439 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-50 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:51,439 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-52 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:51,439 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-58 with 4.15.0-182
2022-06-01 17:06:51,844 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 112512
2022-06-01 17:06:51,844 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2022-06-01 17:06:51,844 DEBUG quirks: running focalPostInitialUpdate
2022-06-01 17:06:51,844 DEBUG running Quirks.focalPostInitialUpdate
2022-06-01 17:06:55,952 DEBUG MetaPkgs: 
2022-06-01 17:07:01,686 DEBUG Foreign: libapache2-mod-php5.6 libargon2-0 libargon2-1 libgd3 libicu64 libicu65 libidn2-0 libodbc1 libpcre16-3 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libsodium23 libxml2 libzip4 libzstd1 mdatp mde-netfilter msodbcsql17 mssql-tools odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 php-common php-imagick php-pear php5.6 php5.6-bcmath php5.6-bz2 php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-dba php5.6-fpm php5.6-gd php5.6-imap php5.6-json php5.6-ldap php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-opcache php5.6-pgsql php5.6-readline php5.6-soap php5.6-sybase php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip php7.2-bcmath php7.2-bz2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-curl php7.2-dba php7.2-dev php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-imagick php7.2-imap php7.2-json php7.2-ldap php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-pgsql php7.2-readline php7.2-soap php7.2-sybase php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-zip php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-imagick php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline unixodbc unixodbc-dev
2022-06-01 17:07:01,686 DEBUG Obsolete: gcc-4.9-base initscripts insserv libcgmanager0 libck-connector0 libevent-2.0-5 libgcr-3-common libgdbm3 libjasper1 libjson-c2 libjson0 libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libpng12-0 libreadline6 libxfont1 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial mountall sysv-rc
2022-06-01 17:07:01,686 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2022-06-01 17:07:01,775 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2022-06-01 17:07:01,779 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2022-06-01 17:07:01,779 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2022-06-01 17:07:01,783 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2022-06-01 17:07:01,786 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,786 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
2022-06-01 17:07:01,786 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/focal/Release
2022-06-01 17:07:01,786 DEBUG s='http' n='at.archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu//dists/focal/Release' q='' f=''
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,807 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,808 DEBUG entry 'deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release
2022-06-01 17:07:01,809 DEBUG s='http' n='security.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release' q='' f=''
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,002 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,003 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,003 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed restricted main multiverse universe'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,003 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal restricted main multiverse universe
2022-06-01 17:07:02,003 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/focal/Release
2022-06-01 17:07:02,003 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu//dists/focal/Release' q='' f=''
2022-06-01 17:07:02,060 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed restricted main multiverse universe' updated to new dist
2022-06-01 17:07:02,060 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,061 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-06-01 17:07:02,061 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main'
2022-06-01 17:07:02,062 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-06-01 17:07:36,564 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2022-06-01 17:07:47,361 DEBUG openCache()
2022-06-01 17:07:49,779 ERROR getListFromFile: no '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/removal_blacklist.cfg' found
2022-06-01 17:07:49,780 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/focal", line 8, in <module>

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2092, in run

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1951, in fullUpgrade

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 214, in openCache

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 242, in _openCache

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 142, in __init__

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeConfigParser.py", line 89, in getListFromFile

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9wzidpju/removal_blacklist.cfg'

2022-06-01 17:07:49,780 DEBUG running apport_crash()
2022-06-01 17:07:49,781 ERROR failed to import apport python module, can't generate crash: No module named 'apport_python_hook'
2022-06-01 17:07:49,781 DEBUG can't find apport
```

cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log:

```
Log time: 2022-06-01 17:06:40.972542
Log time: 2022-06-01 17:06:51.810369
```

Comment: try to install `python3-apport` and do upgrades again.

Comment: After installing `python3-apport`, the upgrade worked successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Install `python3-apport` before running the Upgrade to 20.04LTS.